# How can I refer to only the parent element in Sass?

Tags: css, sass

Apologies for the vague title; I appreciate suggestions. I've looked for similar questions but none seem (to me) to be asking the exact same thing.

Say I have this piece of CSS:

```css
nav a {
    color: blue;
}

nav li.selected a {
    color: red;
}
```

What would be the recommended/preferred/easiest way to achieve this with nesting in Sass? I'd like to target `a` when it's a child of `li.selected` (i.e., referring to exactly one level above itself).

```css
nav {
  a {
    color: blue;

    ??? {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I've tried to no avail:

```css
nav {
  a {
    color: blue;

    li.selected & {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

/* results in li.selected nav a, not nav li.selected a */
```

```css
nav {
  $foo: &;
  a {
    color: blue;

    @at-root #{$foo} li.selected & {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

/* results in nav li.selected nav a, not nav li.selected a */
```

Comment: Unfortunately SASS doesn't have a grandparent selector.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i get it wrong, but is this what you mean?

```
nav {
  a {
    color: blue;
  }
  li.selected a {
      color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is correct, but it requires me to write the `a` selector in two different places. (Not a big deal in this example, but imagine a more complex selector.) I'd think that not having to repeat yourself would be a key feature of Sass, so I'm wondering if there's another way.